# How to keep a fragment running in background which can also be brought to foreground when needed?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Weird but I could not find any related text on this on the net.

I have a fragment with Cordova WebView in it. The app has many other fragments with native list views, etc. User can use the options in Navigation Drawer to switch between the fragments, one of which is the WebView fragment.

I want that the WebView fragment keeps on running in background when it is replaced by another fragment. Later based on user's choice, this fragment might need to be brought to the foreground again.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you call [replace()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace(int,%20android.app.Fragment)), the fragment is removed. You could instead try detaching the fragment from the UI using [detach()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#detach(android.app.Fragment)), and then later recalling it with [attach()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#attach(android.app.Fragment)).

Comment: `detach` destroys the view hierarchy. Will that cause any problem with the WebView? I tried to test this. When the code tried to re-attach the WebView fragment the emulator hanged. So, not sure what happened.

Comment: I'm not sure, I haven't actually done this myself. The other option is to setVisibility of the fragment's views to GONE/VISIBLE depending on desired state.

EDIT

I just noted the show() and hide() methods. Those are probably what you want.